# How to filter a tableview AFTER converting values? LosslessStringConvertible Error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, filtering

I'm making an employee tableview that shows ONLY ID number and Full Name and my goal is to have a filter option using numbers AFTER they have been converted to strings.

Why do I want to convert them? Simple I want show them other employees that start with the search bar numbers. **For example if they type in "524" it would not only show employee 524 (if he/she exists), but also any employee that starts with 524 in the number field.**

**The Problem is:** When trying to convert the int32 to a string I get a LosslessStringConvertible Error

I "Could" rewrite my database and class to make the numbers accept strings instead of integers, BUT I would have to force my current end-users to drop all previous SQL data which is **highly not recommended by my superiors.**

If you have any questions let me know.

I already have code to filter by name below.

```
     func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {
            
            var number : String
        
        if(!isSearchBarEmpty){
        
        if(!isFilterByNumber){
            
            filteredemployee_list = employee_list.filter {
                $0?.employee_name.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
            }
                     
            employeeTableview.reloadData()
     
      }
    
      else{
             //Number filter      

 filteredemployee_list = employee_list.filter {
                String($0?.number).range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil

employeeTableview.reloadData()
        
            }
                
            else{
                 filteredemployee_list = employee_list
                 employeeTableview.reloadData()
            }
```

Comment: Which line here is giving you trouble? I don't see anywhere you're attempting to filter using an employee ID number.

Comment: @AdamPro13 Right where it says number filter in the description comment, I uncommented it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the optional in `String($0?.number)` that's giving you trouble. If you do the following, it should work.

```
filteredEmployees = employees.filter { employee in
   guard let employee = employee else {
      return false
   }
   let range = String(employee.number).range(
      of: searchText, 
      options: .caseInsensitive, 
      range: nil, 
      locale: nil
   )
   return range != nil
}
```

I renamed some of your variables and properties to follow Swift best practices.